# how to turn on Location without permission or Alert in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-location

I wanna to make location Turn on every time i want With Socket.
my problem is what permission should i get of user in first open app .
i dont want show location Alert Dialog for Accept or Delince, just i want one Accept until user uninstall app. 
this is my code with Alert dialog

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("لطفا دسترسی به مکان خود را فعال نمایید.")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("باشه", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("نه", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Comment: if we could bypass the permission model, nobody would be using it :D

Comment: You're saying you need runtime permission if the user denies it should exit the app?

Comment: @DEXTOR_ANTONY  no i say i want get 1 runtime permission forever, and when user location is Off, i turn on her location without asking of user

Comment: @a_local_nobody but i was have an app that i give Allow mock location permission , and everytime my location was off,  the app make it On